# Regular expression replacment for gettyimages

Tags: php, regex

I have editors giving me the embed code from gettyimages in this format:

```
<div class="getty embed image" style="background-color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#a7a7a7;font-size:11px;width:100%;max-width:594px;">
<div style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:left;"><a href="http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/473144498" target="_blank" style="color:#a7a7a7;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal !important;border:none;display:inline-block;">Embed from Getty Images</a></div>
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:0;padding:65.656566% 0 0 0;width:100%;">
<iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/473144498?et=jFJ38un7Qy1YOLsguPNmmA&viewMoreLink=on&sig=YGqYtdBCwZUYgO864KJJ6ulXuBuS1glNjjOGOHCJ28M=&caption=true" width="594" height="390" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;"></iframe>
</div><p style="margin:0;"></p></div>
```

I can't manipulate the image size with all those extra div tags from Gettyimages and tried to replace them to this format:

```
<iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/473144498?et=jFJ38un7Qy1YOLsguPNmmA&viewMoreLink=on&sig=YGqYtdBCwZUYgO864KJJ6ulXuBuS1glNjjOGOHCJ28M=&caption=true" width="594" height="390"></iframe>
```

But I've had no luck so far. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried any regexs or parsers? I wouldn't even know where to start with this question; are you just trying to remove all attributes after `height`?

Comment: I want to keep only the Iframe excluding the css styling inside it

Comment: Use a proper html parser, should be simply a case of selecting the iframe and striping unwanted attributes http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the domdocument parser for this, not a regex.

```
<?php
$string = '<div class="getty embed image" style="background-color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:\'Helvetica Neue\',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#a7a7a7;font-size:11px;width:100%;max-width:594px;">
<div style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:left;"><a href="http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/473144498" target="_blank" style="color:#a7a7a7;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal !important;border:none;display:inline-block;">Embed from Getty Images</a></div>
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:0;padding:65.656566% 0 0 0;width:100%;">
<iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/473144498?et=jFJ38un7Qy1YOLsguPNmmA&viewMoreLink=on&sig=YGqYtdBCwZUYgO864KJJ6ulXuBuS1glNjjOGOHCJ28M=&caption=true" width="594" height="390" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;"></iframe>
</div><p style="margin:0;"></p></div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0)->removeAttribute('style');
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div class="getty embed image" style="background-color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#a7a7a7;font-size:11px;width:100%;max-width:594px;">
<div style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:left;"><a href="http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/473144498" target="_blank" style="color:#a7a7a7;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal !important;border:none;display:inline-block;">Embed from Getty Images</a></div>
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:0;padding:65.656566% 0 0 0;width:100%;">
<iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/473144498?et=jFJ38un7Qy1YOLsguPNmmA&amp;viewMoreLink=on&amp;sig=YGqYtdBCwZUYgO864KJJ6ulXuBuS1glNjjOGOHCJ28M=&amp;caption=true" width="594" height="390" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div><p style="margin:0;"></p></div></body></html>
```

This assumes you only have 1 `iframe`. If you have multiples assign

```
$doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe')
```

to a variable and then iterate through it.

If you only want the `height`, `width`, and `src` attributes it is probably better to select those then build the element. Otherwise you will have to remove every attribute the user could add..

So modifying the above approach:

```
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
foreach($iframes as $iframe) {
     $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');
     $height = $iframe->getAttribute('height');
     $width = $iframe->getAttribute('width');
     echo "<iframe src='$src' height='$height' width='$width'></iframe>";
}
```

This would give:

```
<iframe src='//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/473144498?et=jFJ38un7Qy1YOLsguPNmmA&viewMoreLink=on&sig=YGqYtdBCwZUYgO864KJJ6ulXuBuS1glNjjOGOHCJ28M=&caption=true' height='390' width='594'></iframe>
```

You also could use the `"` for the attribute encapsulation you'll just need to escape them, or concatenate the variables and use single quotes for encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. but I wanted to get this only 
<iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/473144498?et=jFJ38un7Qy1YOLsguPNmmA&viewMoreLink=on&sig=YGqYtdBCwZUYgO864KJJ6ulXuBuS1glNjjOGOHCJ28M=&caption=true" width="594" height="390"></iframe>

Comment: So you only want to output the iframe?

Comment: @chris85: no he want to remove all attributes except: src, width and height.

Comment: `echo "<iframe src='$src' height='$height' width='$width'></iframe>";` doesn't change the document. You need to create a new iframe element to replace the old one.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I think OP only wants the `iframe` element. I will await an answer to my previous comments to him/her though before altering answer again.

Comment: Thanks , now I knew where to start

Answer (score 0):

Too get them all `#(( [a-z]+)="([^"])+")+#` via `perg_match_all`